# How can I display message after form submission

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have created CiviCrm profiles. How can I display a message when user submits the profile? 
First It should display a message (pop or alert) and then redirect to another page.

Answer (score 2):

In the advanced settings of a profile, there is a [**Redirect URL**](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#redirect-url) field. Copying from the CiviCRM user guide:

"This applies only to Profiles that are being used as standalone forms; **it will not apply when the Profile is embedded in an event sign-up or contribution form**. The Redirect URL field allows you to send people to a specific web page after they submit their form. For example, you may want to create a web page that thanks people for submitting their information. If this field is left blank, people will be directed to a page which displays the information they've just entered."

At the top of the default redirect page, a generic statement of "Thank you. Your information has been saved." will be displayed, but this is not a pop-up. If you want to change this wording, you could use Administer > Customize Data and Screens > [**Word Replacements**](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology), but keep in mind that this replacement will be applied globally - i.e. you should ***not*** use this option if you want the wording to be different for each profile submitted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I want to redirect users to thank you page (not default one), before redirecting there should be an alert having thank you message.

Comment: After searching, I found CRM.alert(message, title, type, options) but don't know how to use it.

Comment: For the redirect, you would use the Redirect URL field - as to how to use CRM.alert, I suggest that you post that as a separate question specifically worded "How to use CRM.alert?" being sure to include the workflow that you are trying to achieve. Good luck!